seaborn countplot that only counts total number of data points below and above a threshold
Here's my data structure:
betterTrue = [random.randint(0,1) for x in range(500)]
betterFalse = [(x + 1) % 2 for x in betterTrue]

data = {
    "model": ["A" for x in range(500)] + ["B" for x in range(500)],
    "safety": [random.randint(0,4) for x in range(1000)],
    "honesty": [random.randint(0,4) for x in range(1000)],
    "quality": [random.randint(0,4) for x in range(1000)],
    "better": betterTrue + betterFalse
}

I'd like to generate count plots comparing each model's performance in each of the safety, honesty, quality, and better columns. For the first three, the data comes in integer values from 0 to 5, and for better, the data is either 0 or 1.
But for the first three columns, I only care if the data point is greater than or equal to 3 or less than 3. Is there a way to generate a count plot which throws the data into two bins >= 3 and < 3?
For reference, this is what it looks like when we don't do that, and instead just discretely bin by each possible value
fig = sns.countplot(x = 'safety', hue='model', data=data, stat='count')

You can create an extra column, e.g. data["good quality"] = [0 if q < 3 else 1 for q in data["quality"]] and create the plot with that one.  Note that sns.countplot doesn't return a fig (it returns an ax); using fig will lead to confusion when you try to mimic example code.   Also note that the numpy library makes working with large lists of number faster and has an easier notation (once you get used to it).

@JohanC Thank you, and yes that clarification does clear up some issues I was having with generating multiple figures. Is there a figure-level function variant for the countplot function?

@JohanC Got it. If I wanted to generate several count plots, what would be the best way forward? I could just comment each one out and generate them one by one but that’s not a particularly useful pipeline.

There are many ways to convert ranges of values to just a few. A pure Python way would be data["good quality"] = [0 if q < 3 else 1 for q in data["quality"]]. Instead of 0 and 1, you could also use strings.
When working with large arrays of numbers, numpy offers both speed and a powerfull array notation.
The code below uses numpy to create the random arrays (for some mystical reason, random.randint() and np.random.randint() interpret their second parameter differently). The code uses pd.cut() to efficiently map ranges of numbers to strings.
plt.subplots() creates a figure with multiple subplots.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

betterTrue = np.random.randint(0, 2, 500)
betterFalse = 1 - betterTrue

data = {
    "model": np.repeat(["A", "B"], 500),
    "safety": np.random.randint(0, 5, 1000),
    "honesty": np.random.randint(0, 5, 1000),
    "quality": np.random.randint(0, 5, 1000),
    "better": np.concatenate([betterTrue, betterFalse])
}

# choose a seaborn style
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
# create a figure with subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, figsize=(12, 7))

# flatten the array of axes
axs = axs.flatten()

# create a countplot for each of the desired columns
for column, ax in zip(data.keys(), axs):
    column_data = data[column] if column != 'quality' else pd.cut(data[column], bins=[0, 2, 4],
                                                                  labels=["bad", "good"])
    sns.countplot(x=column_data, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel(column)

# remove the unused subplots
for ax in axs[len(data):]:
    ax.remove()

# remove upper and right spine
sns.despine()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Thank you, this is helpful. I was hoping there was a way to generate plots with modified / collate data from the data frame without modifying the data frame but this will do very well regardless

I updated the answer with a version that doesn't change the original dataframe.
